# PHP Timestamp and if statement

Tags: php, mysql

Im using timestamps with my sql database.
I currently am making a voting system, can anyone make a if statement where if $stamp is older than two days it will run some code? i have been trying for hours and can't seem to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: What format is the timestamp? Numeric Unix timestamp or SQL timestamp etc?

Comment: @Ben Swinburne what is the difference between unix timestamp and mysql timestamp?

Comment: A MySQL timestamp looks like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and would typically be associated with a column of type TIMESTAMP and a Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since the epoch and looks something like 1319533396 and would usually be stored in a field of type INT or BIGINT.

Comment: this is an example 2011-11-01 00:24:42

Comment: Needs more info. *What* code? And in *what* language, PHP or SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need PHP to do this for you, let the database do the work as it's usually more efficient:

```
SELECT * FROM votes WHERE vote_timestamp <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

I believe this also work with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, `TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME` and `DATE` columns as MySQL will perform the conversion automatically and apply it to the result set.

Comment: $get_stamps = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 48hrvotes WHERE vote_timestamp <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_stamps))
  {
   echo $row['time'];
  }

How comes this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: You're missing the closing parenthesis on the `DATE_SUB` function.

Answer (score 0):

[time()](http://php.net/time) will give you the current time stamp. this number is in seconds.
So, everything with a timestamp which is less than `time()-(2*24*60*60)` is what you look for.

b.t.w usually people are reluctant to help if you do not show what you tried (or that u even tried).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if you're using a unix timestamp:

```
$two_days_ago = strtotime('-2 days');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp_column < ' . $two_days_ago;
```

If your column is a MySQL timestamp (as others have mentioned) it would look more like this:

```
$two_days_ago = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-2 days'));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp_column < '" . $two_days_ago . "'";
```